# Why is the Write system call in not writing anything to the sockets file?

Tags: linux, sockets, server, client

I am writing a simple Server Client program that exchanges the data. After I write to the socket file, the write doesn't fail or it is not even partial write. but when I check the details of the socket file using ls -l , I still see it's size as zero and server doesn't recieve anything. Can anyone help me out with what I am doing wrong in here??

This is server.c

```
int main()
{
    int socket_fd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    int result = -1;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    printf("Creating a socket\n");
    socket_fd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(socket_fd == -1)
    {
        perror("SOCKET");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Socket has been created %d\n",socket_fd);

    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path,_SOCKET_PATH,sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);

    printf("PATH : %s\n",addr.sun_path);

    if(remove(_SOCKET_PATH) == -1)
    {
        perror("REMOVE");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Binding the socket\n");
    result = bind(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    if(result == -1)
    {
        perror("BIND");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Binding the socket is done\n");

    printf("Listening to the socket\n");

    if(listen(socket_fd,1) == -1)
    {
        perror("Listen");
        return 0;
    }

    if((result = accept(socket_fd,NULL,NULL)) == -1)
    {
        perror("ACCEPT");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Connection Accepted\n");

    while (1)
    {
        while (result = read(socket_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1) > 0)
        {
            printf("Client said : %s\n",buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is client.c

```
int main()
{
    int socket_fd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    int result = -1;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    printf("Creating a socket\n");
    socket_fd = socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(socket_fd == -1)
    {
        perror("SOCKET");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Socket has been found %d\n",socket_fd);

    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path,_SOCKET_PATH,sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);

    printf("Connecting to the socket\n");
    result = connect(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    if(result == -1)
    {
        perror("CONNECT");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("The client is connected to the server.\n");

    while (1)
    {
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        scanf("%s",buffer);
        printf("DATA WRITTEN %s,%d\n",buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
        result = write(socket_fd,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1);
        printf("result = %d\n",result);
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((result = accept(socket_fd,NULL,NULL)) == -1)
...
    while (result = read(socket_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1) > 0)
```

You are trying to read from the server socket (`socket_fd`). Instead you need to read from the new socket returned by `accept`, i.e. what you call `result` in `result = accept...`.  To cite from [man accept](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> On success, these system calls return a nonnegative integer **that is a
>          file descriptor for the accepted socket**.  On error, -1 is returned,
>          and errno is set appropriately.